# Evitar dependencia particular en la generación de un paquete rpm

Tags: linux, rpm

Tengo un problema a la hora de generar un paquete rpm.

Mi aplicación es una aplicación que gestiona una BBDD por lo que los binarios están compilados contra una librería, entre otras, del motor BBDD que es Firebird.

El problema es que dicha librería está instalada a través de un fichero "tar" y no por RPM, por lo que al instalar mi paquete me veo obligado a realizarlo con la opción `--nodeps` de RPMs ya que si no, me da errores de dependencia con dicha librería.

En resumen, ¿qué opciones poner o qué macro puedo usar en el fichero ".spec" para que el paquete "rpm resultante" se pueda instalar obviando dicha dependencia?

Os agradezco mucho por adelantado que me podáis echar una mano al respecto.